# RegExp help in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need a regexp that can validate a string for the following criteria.

- The string must be comprised of capital letters only.
- It must have minimum of 6 and maximum of 20 characters in it.
- It must begin with a  substring - ROLE (capital only) followed by an underscore  character like ROLE_
- The underscore character must **not** appear at the end of the string (neither at the beginning).
- The remaining characters should only be a combination of capital letters and underscores like ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_AGENT_USER.
- Two or more consecutive underscores should be disallowed.

Since I know a very little about regexp, the examples which have been attempted so far by me are pretty much unacceptable and I feel, they are quite unnecessary to present here.

Comment: Well, let's try to start from scratch.  What do you think the regular expression should look like?  Showing what you've got would be beneficial not only to yourself but to us - we can help you with what you've not quite got right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my regular expression.

```
(?!.*__.*)(?!.*_$)(ROLE_[A-Z_]{1,15})
```

Here's what it does:

- Those portions in front are called [*negative lookaheads.*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  They reject the string if there are more than two consecutive underscores in it, or if there's one at the end.
- The next group matches the verbatim string `ROLE_`, then any other character A-Z and underscore, at least once but no more than 15 times.  This keeps the overall string length to 20 or less.

[Here's what it looks like on Debuggex.](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28%3F%21.%2A__.%2A%29%28%3F%21.%2A_%24%29%28ROLE_%5BA-Z_%5D%7B1%2C15%7D%29&str=)

Comment: This allows a underscore as the last character

Comment: @Pescis:  Inb4 remark.

Comment: +1 for speed of lightning! Also, nice regex.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, checking the length of the string with regex makes it complicated, but you can use the following:

```
^ROLE_(([A-Z]+_)*[A-Z]+)(?<!.{21})$
```

`(?<!.{21})` basically rejects the string if it's length is more than 20

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/f6PPFGm8Eg) is a demo on Rubular.

---

if your regex flavor doesn't support negative lookbehinds, you can use

```
^(?!.{21,})ROLE_(([A-Z]+_)*[A-Z]+)$
```

`(?!.{21,})` does the same as `(?<!.{21})` but checks the length first.

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/o6saoaG5Fw) is a demo on Rubular.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
ROLE(_[A-Z]+)+
```

This won't limit the maximum length, but I think this is the closest you'll get.

Comment: No...you can definitely get closer.